# Circular dependency when providing a service in an Angular 6 / Ionic 4 feature module

Tags: angular, ionic-framework

I have an Ionic 3 application I am porting over to Ionic 4, and I now want to use lazy loading for my Pages (Components). So I am dividing the app into feature modules.

While most of my services will be in a single `Core` shared module (provided in `root`), there are a few cases where I have `Services` that are only used by a single Page's module, so I thought I would include the service in the feature module.

From what I have read, using the `providedIn` is the "new way" to provide services.

So, I initially had the following:

```
    // home.module.ts
    import { HomePage } from './home.page';
    import { HomeRoutingModule } from './home-routing.module';

    @NgModule({
      imports: [
        CommonModule,
        TranslateModule.forChild(),
        FormsModule,
        IonicModule,
        HomeRoutingModule
      ],
      providers: [],  // <--- note no providers
      declarations: [HomePage, HomeRoutingModule.components]
    })
    export class HomePageModule {}

    // home-routing.module.ts
    import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
    import { RouterModule, Routes } from '@angular/router';
    import { HomePage } from './home.page';

    const routes: Routes = [
      { path: '', component: HomePage }
    ];
    @NgModule({
      imports: [RouterModule.forChild(routes)],
      exports: [RouterModule]
    })
    export class HomeRoutingModule {
      static components = [HomePage];
    }
```

And in the service, I used the `providedIn`:

```
    import { HomePageModule } from '../home.module';

    @Injectable({
      providedIn: HomePageModule
    })
    export class AvailablePagesService {
    ...
```

If I run this as is, the service is not found:

```
ERROR Error: Uncaught (in promise): Error: StaticInjectorError(AppModule)[HomePage -> AvailablePagesService]: 
      StaticInjectorError(Platform: core)[HomePage -> AvailablePagesService]: 
        NullInjectorError: No provider for AvailablePagesService!
    Error: StaticInjectorError(AppModule)[HomePage -> AvailablePagesService]: 
      StaticInjectorError(Platform: core)[HomePage -> AvailablePagesService]: 
        NullInjectorError: No provider for AvailablePagesService!
        at NullInjector.push../node_modules/@angular/core/fesm5/core.js.NullInjector.get (core.js:8896)
```

So I added the service to the Modiles provider array.

Ie in `home.module.ts` I add:

```
 providers: [AvailablePagesService],
```

Now, this gives me a circular dependency warning (3 times):

```
    WARNING in Circular dependency detected:
    [ng] src\app\home\home-routing.module.ts -> src\app\home\home.page.ts -> src\app\home\services\available-pages.service.ts -> src\app\home\home.module.ts -> src\app\home\home-routing.module.ts
```

I then tried the following:

```
 providers: [HomePageModule],
```

Now I get the same injector error again (can't find the service).

I am quite confused on how I can do this.

Comment: Did you remove `{ providedIn: HomePageModule }` when you add service to module `providers: [HomePageModule],`?

Comment: @Ivanes, no I didn't. I removed this and now (at least this part) works fine. Re-reading the doco on `providedIn`, perhaps this can only be used for app wide providers, and only when you use 'root'. Actually can't see the point with the since you can still just use the. eg all my services in my `core` I have both `providedIn: 'root'` and I declare them in in the modules `providers` array. I have just realised I don't understand these modules at all (:-(), as I now have other problems (but that is offtopic here and for another post)

Answer (score 0):

It happens because your **imports** have a circle (<- sign is depends on):

`routing <- component <- service <- module <- routing`

And when webpack try to resolve imports, it have a trouble with infinite package embedding. In your case the best way to:
`module <- component && service && routing`
`component <- service`
`routing<- component`
`service <- (nothing)`

In **module.ts**

```
import { AvailablePagesService } from './available-pages.service.ts';
import { PageComponent } from './home.page';

...
@NgModule({
      declarations: [HomePage, ...]
      imports: [RouterModule.forChild(routes)],
      providers: [AvailablePagesService ]
})
```

In **available-pages.service.ts**

```
@Injectable()
export class AvailablePagesService {
...
```

In **home.page**

```
import { AvailablePagesService } from './available-pages.service.ts';
...
```